# C# equivalent of the Ruby symbol

Tags: c#, ruby, symbols

I'm developing a little C# application for the fun. I love this language but something disturb me ...

Is there any way to do a #define (C mode) or a symbol (ruby mode).

The ruby symbol is quite useful. It's just some name preceded by a ":" (example ":guy") every symbol is unique and can be use any where in the code.

In my case I'd like to send a flag (connect or disconnect) to a function.

What is the most elegant C# way to do that ?

Here is what i'd like to do :

```
BgWorker.RunWorkersAsync(:connect)
//...

private void BgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Arguement == :connect)
    //Do the job
}
```

At this point the my favorite answer is the enum solution ;)

Comment: It might be worth your while putting in a small example of C or Ruby code to better demonstrate _exactly_ how you'd like to put this connect/disconnect flag of yours to use.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Since I'm not familiar with Ruby, can symbols be declared dynamically at run-time? That's the impression I get based on how you'd like to use them here.

Comment: @Xiaofu Symbols doesn't need to be declared, ruby will automatically assign a value to them when it reads them for the first time. The same value is reused if the same same symbol occur again in the code. 2 symbols can't have the same value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, sending a flag can be done by using an enum...

```
public enum Message
{
  Connect,
  Disconnect
}

public void Action(Message msg)
{
   switch(msg)
   {
      case Message.Connect: 
         //do connect here
       break;
      case Message.Disconnect: 
          //disconnect
       break;
      default:
          //Fail!
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a string constant:

```
public const string Guy = "guy";
```

In fact strings in .NET are special. If you declare two string variable with the same value they actually point to the same object:

```
string a = "guy";
string b = "guy";
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); // prints True
```

Comment: Printing the hash code doesn't show that they're referencing the same object - use object.ReferenceEquals instead. (They *will*, due to literal interning - but your code doesn't actually prove it.)

Comment: The hash code will match even if they don't point to the same object.  The hash code is calculated from the string's contents, not from its memory location.  And I wouldn't rely on strings being interned.  This is only for literal strings and I would say it's an implementation detail.  If you want to be sure that two equivalent strings are indeed the same object, use `string.Intern()`.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't support C-style macros, although it does still have #define. For their reasoning on this take a look at the [csharp FAQ blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/09/86979.aspx) on msdn.

If your flag is for conditional compilation purposes, then you can still do this:

```
#define MY_FLAG

#if MY_FLAG
  //do something
#endif
```

But if not, then what you're describing is a configuration option and should perhaps be stored in a class variable or config file instead of a macro.

Comment: Yes i know this method, it's all but elegant :p In C the define can be use into condition or as function parameters.

Comment: Macros used as method substitutes or as global variables tend to obscure the situation in my opinion, and obscurity is anything but elegant. ;) But of course you may well have other things in mind beyond that.

Comment: Look at what you can do with ruby symbols ;) http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Darin but I often create a Defs class in my project to put all such constants so there is an easy way to access them from anywhere.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string s = Defs.pi;
    }
}
class Defs
{

    public const int Val = 5;
    public const string pi = "3.1459";
}
```

Comment: Const are static by default take a look at this http://abdullin.com/how-to-run-free-ncover-on-a-64-bit-machine/

Comment: I think jmservera is referring to marking the *class* as static.  `static class Defs{}`

Comment: A bit off topic, but you should use Math.PI in computations.  I know it's just an example but may mislead a new programmer to think they need to define PI in their application.